# Java reading SWF and outputting to browser SocketCloseException

Tags: java, actionscript-3, sockets

function for reading `swf`, I'am using it also for images, but images are loaded ok:

```
public static InputStream readImage(String file) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

        return input;
}
```

and here the last function for output where I'am passing the input stream:

```
  public static void writeImage(InputStream input) {

    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        byte[] bytesSend;
        int bytesRead;
        /*
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            responseBody.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        */
        IOUtils.copy(input, responseBody);
        responseBody.flush();
        responseBody.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("bbbb");
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);

    }

  }
```

I've tried to use both the `IOUtils.copy` AND the `while loop`, i get the following errors:

```
sun.net.httpserver.StreamClosedException

java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException
```

The SWF file has modules that are loaded too, so there are 4-5 swf requests..

Which server implementation I'am using?

```
public void run() {
    try
    {
        InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(8080);
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(addr, 0);

        server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server is listening on port 8080" );
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Http point error");
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Maybe somone has some ideas about this, I can provide more info if needed

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the browser is deciding to stop reading the image file part way through.

One possibility is that you haven't set the right content type in the response.

Another is that you've arranged the browser side (e.g. in your HTML or Javascript) to "GET" the SWF document in a context where it makes no sense.

Comment: I've setted the content-type its application/x-shockwave-flash, what you mean by "arrange the browser side"? no its not about images, its about SWF, sometimes its loads successfully, but then the sockets are closed, I have http and sockets in one programm running paralell

Comment: If it is not about images, why do you call the methods `readImage` and `writeImage` ???

Comment: Either way, I think that it is something to do with what happens on the browser side.  Is anything showing up in your browser's web development UI / logs?

Comment: yes the application flash is displayed, but not all modules are loaded or even no one is loaded

Comment: I use the readImage and writeImage for the SWF and Images, they both work, the swf are loaded to the browser, but I can't understand why the error are ocurring